# C++ Fast base convertions, digits count

Tags: c++, count, converters, radix

I have to write an app in which the user give the length of digital array and the base in which the sum of the array element will be converted into. Then the user gives an array. The app must sum the given elements, then convert the sum into given base and count the digits of the sum. What is more, it should also print how many digits was given as an input.
So for example an

```
input is:
  3 10 // 3 - length, 10 - base
  1 2 3 // array
And the output:
1 // number of digits of the sum in base 10
6 // number of digits in input
```

Another example:

```
Input:
3 2
1 2 3
Output:
3 
5
```

What I have written so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void convert(int N, int b)
{
//int result = 0;
if (N == 0)
    return ;

int x = N % b;
N /= b;
if (x < 0)
    N += 1;
convert(N, b);

cout << (x < 0 ? x + (b * -1) : x);
return;
```

}

```
int countDigits(int number) {
    if (number < 10) {
        return 1;
}
int count = 0;
while (number > 0) {
    number /= 10;
    count++;
}
return count;
```

}

```
int main()
{
int n, d;
cin >> n >> d;

int a;
long long int sum = 0;

int count = 0;
while (count++ < n) {
    cin >> a;
    sum += a;
}

cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl << "Diff Base: ";

if (sum != 0)
{
    convert(sum, d);
    cout << endl;
}
else
    cout << "0" << endl;
return 0;
```

}

The problem is that I don't know how to change the convert function to int, so then I can easily pass the return into countDigits function. And also I have no idea how to count the input digits. It should be as much efficient as possible.

Comment: maybe you can explain more? especially how each output is calculated.

Comment: Well, firstly I count the sum of the array. Sum is counted in main. Then I use function convert, to convert the sum to the given base. The problem is that my function convert is void type, so I can't pass the result to the function countDigits. Because if I could then I'll be done with the first output: sum -> convert to base -> count the digits.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a function that just does: sum -> digits with the specified base. You'll have a harder time of representing your sum in an unspecified base and then counting its digits. The function below should cover a wide range of bases.

```
int nr_digits_in_base(long long int N, int B)
{
    assert(B > 1);
    int nr_digits_to_represent_N_in_base_B = N < 0 ? 2 : 1;
    while (N /= B)
        nr_digits_to_represent_N_in_base_B++;
    return nr_digits_to_represent_N_in_base_B;
}
```

Alternatively, there's is a way using logarithms to calculate the answer in fixed time.